# Convert Derivative[1][f] to f'

Tags: differential-equations, front-end, output-formatting, display

I believe this is a *little* problem that everybody asking or answering ODE related question in this site suffers.

We know derivative of a variable, say, `f`, can be inputted as

```
f'
```

But once the `f'` is executed, or we just keystrokes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to convert it to `StandardForm`, it'll become

[image]

Convert it to `InputForm` by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, or copy and paste it to this site or any text editor, what we obtain is

```
Derivative[1][f]
```

Not too bad, but still less concise compared to `f'`. What's the simplest way to convert it back to `f'`?

Ideally, can we modify the behavior of Convert to `InputForm`?

`f'` above is just an example. I'm expecting a solution that handles `Derivative[n][f]` where `n` is an integer, of course.

Comment: So what do you want to paste for `n=5`?

Comment: @Kuba `f'''''` :) Well, I know it no longer looks good, but extremely high order derivative doesn't come up often when dealing with ODEs. And I think it won't be too hard to limit the solution to e.g. `n<=4` case, if we can figure out one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) to control how derivatives are copy/pasted:

```
MakeBoxes[Derivative[n_Integer?(Between[{1,4}])][f_], StandardForm] := With[
    {p=StringRepeat["\[Prime]",n], q=StringRepeat["'",n]},
    TemplateBox[
        {MakeBoxes[f]},
        "Derivative1",
        DisplayFunction->(SuperscriptBox[#1, p, MultilineFunction->None]&),
        InterpretationFunction->(RowBox[{#1, q}]&)
    ]
]

MakeBoxes[Derivative[n__Integer][f_], StandardForm] := TemplateBox[
    {MakeBoxes[f], RowBox[BoxForm`MakeInfixForm[{n}, ",", StandardForm]]},
    "Derivative2",
    DisplayFunction->(SuperscriptBox[#1, RowBox[{"(",#2,")"}],MultilineFunction->None]&),
    InterpretationFunction->(RowBox[{RowBox[{"Derivative", "[", #2,"]"}],"[",#1,"]"}]&)
]
```

Comment: Oh you've readily resolved the other _little_ problem i.e. the direct copying of high order derivative and partial derivative in `StandardForm` :D .

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to override `Derivative` box formatting and use `Copy As -> Plain Text`

```
MakeBoxes[Derivative[n_Integer][f_], form_] := RowBox[{ToBoxes@f, StringRepeat["'", n]}]
```

Comment: It turns out to be unnecessary to copy as plain text, Ctrl+Shift+N works, too.