# Problem with a DAE and DiscreteVariables

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, bugs, event-detection

**Cross-posted [in Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2546305).**

---

I am solving an DAE problem with `NDSolve`. It is a physical problem related to friction forces: one mass on the X axis and another on the Y axis, linked by a bar (L=5). There is a part of the equation that must change the sign (the one related to a[t]), and I try to control it by `a[t]`. I am able to solve this problem as it is a piecewise problem but I would like to solve it as a whole, so I have tried to use `WhenEvent` and `DiscreteVariables`.
I use:

```
deqns= {
  x''[t] == -(1/5) T[t] x[t] + 0.1 a[t] (9.8 + 1/5 T[t] (3 + y[t])), 
  y''[t] == (49 - 2/5 T[t] (3 + y[t]))/5, x[t]^2 + (3 + y[t])^2 == 25,
  WhenEvent[x'[t] == 0, a[t] -> -a[t]],
  x[0] == 4, y[0] == 0, a[0] == 1,
  x'[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0};

sol = NDSolve[
  deqns, {x, y, T, a}, {t, 0, 10},
  DiscreteVariables -> a,
  Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic}
];
```

Physical constraints force -4 <= x[t] <= 4, and 0 <= y[t] <=2.
My question is about solution obtained for a[t]. It is defined as "DiscreteVariables", and a[t] should change between -1 and +1 but when I plot it, it is not true.
Any suggestion?

Art

Thank you @bbgodfrey for your comments, but I think the original DAE are corrects. As I previously mentioned, a piecewise solution is easy to obtain. I include this solution for x, y, x' and y' obtained by composing the partial solutions until the mechanical problem stop.
[image]
[image]

I have posted another question on this problem in a new thread: [Problem with a DAE and DiscreteVariables (II)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269890/problem-with-a-dae-and-discretevariables-ii)

Comment: Maybe `y''[t] == (49 - 2/5 T[t] (3 + y[t]))/5`.

Comment: What's an "ADE"?

Comment: @ChrisK Probably, DAE is meant.

Comment: My guess is that this is a bug.

Comment: Sorry, a typo. It is a DAE, a Differential-Algebraic Equation.

Comment: In the original equations, there is a comma "," after x''.

Comment: There are two differential equations, one for x'' and another for y'', and an algebraic equation. Coefficient 49 correspond to differential equation for y''. Comma after x'' is missing. My problem comes plotting a[t]. It should  be a discrete variable taking values between -1 and +1, but the plot is very different to this. Sorry again for the typos.

Comment: y'' can be rewritten as @cvgmt says. Art

Comment: Why not edit the original equations and title about this question.

Comment: Edit done @cvgmt

Comment: Same behavior in _v9.0.1_. Looks like a bug. Please report it to WRI. As to work-around: transforming the system to an ODE system should help.

Comment: @xzczd Reported to WRI. Thank you for your suggestion. The problem is not very difficult to solve. It was the unexpected result what I reported. I don't understand the reason for it.

Comment: Should the term `9.8` be multiplied by `a[t]`?

Comment: @bbgodfrey a[t] is introduced to control the friction coefficient (given in this case by 0.1) depending on the direction of movement.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.  I have added a second approach to my answer that exactly reproduces the plots you have added to your question.

Comment: Thanks to you because your solution was what I was looking for.

Comment: My first idea was to use DiscreteVariables, but I was surprised by the results on a[t]. This was the reason for posting here. Your solution circumvents in a very compact way the problem. The calculations must end at t=4.62685 because the mass in the X axis stops its movement. This can be checked simply looking at sucessive values of your variable "init": position x is positive for t=3.20965 (x'=0)  and change in "a" (movement to left) and x also positive in t=4.62685 (x'=0) and no chance to continue the movement.

Comment: Please add cross links between this and the related post on Wolfram Community.

Comment: This is the link: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2546305

Comment: Please post the code about the last pictures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the question, `a[t]` does not behave properly for the code in the question, which probably is a bug. Circumventing this problem can be accomplished with

```
sol = NDSolveValue[deqns, {x[t], y[t], T[t], a[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, 
    DiscreteVariables -> a, 
    Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> {Automatic, "IndexGoal" -> 0}}];
```

in which case,

```
Plot[sol[[4]], {t, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {t, a}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

However, results for `{x, y}` are discontinuous, which is troubling.

```
Plot[Evaluate@sol[[;; 3]], {t, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {t, "x,y,T"}, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

**Edit: Solution with continuous {x, y}**

Further consideration of the comprehensive [DAE documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDAE.html) suggests another approach, namely replacing the constraint equation, `deqns[[3]]`, by its second derivative, thereby reducing the index of this DAE system from three to one.

```
sol1 = NDSolveValue[deqns /. deqns[[3]] -> D[deqns[[3]], {t, 2}], 
    {x[t], y[t], T[t], a[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, DiscreteVariables -> a, 
    Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic}];
```

Plotting the results as before yields

[image]

A blowup of this plot over the domain `{t, 0, 4.62685}` exactly reproduces the first plot recently added to the question, as desired.  Because `deqns[[3]]` is not actually used here, it is natural to ask how well it is satisfied.  Plotting

```
(Subtract @@ deqns[[3]]) /. Thread[{x[t], y[t]} -> sol1[[;; 2]]];
Plot[%, {t, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {t, err}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

demonstrates that this constraint remains well satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

One can keep differentiating until the DAE turns into an ODE:

```
deqns = {Derivative[3][y][t] == 
     (4*(-3*T[t]*x[t]*Derivative[1][x][t] - 
        T[t]*x[t]*y[t]*Derivative[1][x][t] + 
        T[t]*x[t]^2*Derivative[1][y][t] + 
        45*Derivative[1][x][t]*Derivative[2][x][t] + 
        15*y[t]*Derivative[1][x][t]*Derivative[2][x][t] + 
        45*Derivative[1][y][t]*Derivative[2][y][t] + 
        15*y[t]*Derivative[1][y][t]*Derivative[2][y][t]))/
      (5*(-36 + 3*a[t]*x[t] - 10*x[t]^2 - 24*y[t] + 
        a[t]*x[t]*y[t] - 4*y[t]^2)), 
    Derivative[3][x][t] == 
     (-3*Derivative[1][x][t]*Derivative[2][x][t] - 
       3*Derivative[1][y][t]*Derivative[2][y][t] - 
       3*Derivative[3][y][t] - y[t]*Derivative[3][y][t])/
      x[t], Derivative[1][T][t] == 
     (-2*T[t]*Derivative[1][y][t] - 
       25*Derivative[3][y][t])/(2*(3 + y[t])), 
    WhenEvent[Derivative[1][x][t] == 0, {a[t] -> -a[t]}], 
    {T[0] == 9.054347826086959, Derivative[2][x][0] == 
      -5.720217391304348, Derivative[2][y][0] == 
      7.62695652173913}, x[0] == 4, y[0] == 0, a[0] == 1, 
    Derivative[1][x][0] == 0, Derivative[1][y][0] == 0}; 
sol = NDSolve[deqns, {x, y, T, a}, {t, 0, 10}, 
   DiscreteVariables -> {Element[a, {-1, 1}]}]

Values@sol // Flatten // ListLinePlot
```

[image]

```
Show[%, PlotRange -> {-3, 4}]
```

[image]

To get the system, `Reduce` as follows, but `Reduce` fails to solve for `y'''[t]`. It solves for `a[t]`. (Why on earth???) Anyway, pluck that equation out of the morass of output and solve it for `y'''[t]` and use the solutions for `x'''[t]` and `T'[t]`.  There are a lot of edge cases to ignore, and I hope I didn't ignore anything important. Then solve the original system for the missing initial conditions need due to raising the differential order.

```
Reduce[{D[Derivative[2][x][t] == (-(1/5))*T[t]*x[t] + 
       (1/10)*a[t]*(98/10 + (1/5)*T[t]*(3 + y[t])), t] /. 
    Derivative[1][a][t] -> 0, 
   D[Derivative[2][y][t] == (49 - (2/5)*T[t]*(3 + y[t]))/
      5, t], D[x[t]^2 + (3 + y[t])^2 == 25, {t, 3}]}, 
  {Derivative[3][x][t], Derivative[3][y][y], 
   Derivative[1][T][t]}]

Solve[a[t] == (2*(-6*T[t]*x[t]*Derivative[1][x][t] - 
      2*T[t]*x[t]*y[t]*Derivative[1][x][t] + 
      2*T[t]*x[t]^2*Derivative[1][y][t] + 
      90*Derivative[1][x][t]*Derivative[2][x][t] + 
      30*y[t]*Derivative[1][x][t]*Derivative[2][x][t] + 
      90*Derivative[1][y][t]*Derivative[2][y][t] + 
      30*y[t]*Derivative[1][y][t]*Derivative[2][y][t] + 
      90*Derivative[3][y][t] + 25*x[t]^2*
       Derivative[3][y][t] + 60*y[t]*Derivative[3][y][t] + 
      10*y[t]^2*Derivative[3][y][t]))/(5*x[t]*(3 + y[t])*
     Derivative[3][y][t]), Derivative[3][y][t]]

{Derivative[2][x][t] == (-(1/5))*T[t]*x[t] + 
      0.1*a[t]*(9.8 + (1/5)*T[t]*(3 + y[t])), 
    Derivative[2][y][t] == (49 - (2/5)*T[t]*(3 + y[t]))/5, 
    D[x[t]^2 + (3 + y[t])^2 == 25, {t, 2}]} /. t -> 0 /. 
  Solve[{x[0] == 4, y[0] == 0, a[0] == 1, 
    Derivative[1][x][0] == 0, Derivative[1][y][0] == 0}]
(*
{{Derivative[2][x][0] == 0.1*(9.8 + (3*T[0])/5) - 
     (4*T[0])/5, Derivative[2][y][0] == 
    (1/5)*(49 - (6*T[0])/5), 
   8*Derivative[2][x][0] + 6*Derivative[2][y][0] == 0}}
*)

Solve /@ %
(*
{{{T[0] -> 9.054347826086959, Derivative[2][x][0] -> 
     -5.720217391304348, Derivative[2][y][0] -> 
     7.62695652173913}}}
*)
```

Gosh I wish that in addition to `InputForm` and `RawInputForm` we had <*expletive*> `NormalInputForm`.

Comment: To convert `Derivative` to `'`, you may want to try this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/231436/1871