# Problem with a DAE and DiscreteVariables (II)

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, event-detection

I continue with a DAE problem similar to another one posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/269096/1871) some days ago. @bbgodfrey offered a solution for the `DiscreteVariables` problem but now I have a different problem.

Equations I put came from a simple dynamic problem: A mass m1 initially at rest at `x == x0` at time `t == 0` is attached to another mass `m2` (initial position `y0`) through a bar (without mass). Friction model is static. It is an example of motion under a variable force. `a[t]` is used to model the friction force as opposed to movement. Thus `a[t]` must change between `-1` and `1`. The problem can be easily solved by parts, distinguishing sections by `x'[t] == 0`. The final situation must be mass `m1` and mass `m2` stopped in some point.

Equations I sent you correspond to concrete values for `m1`, `m2`, `x0`, `y0`, and `mu` (friction coefficient).

My problem is as follows: when I execute

```
g = 9.8; m1 = 1; m2 = 5; x0 = 4; y0 = 10; μ0 = 0.1;

deqns1 = 
  {-T[t] x[t]/Sqrt[x0^2 + y0^2] + 
     μ0 a[t] (m1 g + T[t] (y0 + y[t])/Sqrt[x0^2 + y0^2]) == m1 x''[t], 

   m2 g - 2 T[t] (y0 + y[t])/Sqrt[x0^2 + y0^2] == m2 y''[t], 

   WhenEvent[x'[t] == 0 && t > 10^-6, 
     {a[t] -> -a[t], Sow[{t, x[t]}], i = i + 1, new = Sign[x[t]], 
     If[new != old, {old = new; Print[{t, a[t]}]}, 
                    {end = t; "StopIntegration"}]}]};

aeqns1 = {(x[t])^2 + (y0 + y[t])^2 == x0^2 + y0^2};

ics1 = {x[0] == x0, y[0] == 0, a[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0};

old = Sign[x0]; i = 0; 
{sol, points} = Reap@NDSolve[{deqns1, D[aeqns1, {t, 2}], ics1}, 
  {x, y, T, a}, {t, 0, 20}, DiscreteVariables -> a, Method -> 
  "IndexReduction" -> {True}];

Plot[{x[t] /. sol, y[t] /. sol, a[t] /. sol}, {t, 0, end}, 
  AxesLabel -> {t, "x,y"}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"x[t]", "y[t]"}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point@@points}, 
  LabelStyle -> {12, Black}]
```

an unexpected result is obtained:
[image]

Solution for `a[t] == -1` is not correct. When the differential equations are solved in a piecewise way, the movement stops at `t == 2.11`.

It seems there is some kind of problem fixing the initial conditions in the compact solution at `t == 2.11` because the obtained results are incorrect, but I am unable to know why.

As I have mentioned, this malfunction is observed only for some combinations of initial variables.

**Final Solution**: After comments of @xzczd, I have reformulated the equations without `T[t]` and rationalized the resulting equation. Additionally, I have substitued `a[t]` by `Sign[x'[t]]`. Results are now according with the ones expected from a physical point of view. Thank you very much for your feedback.

```
g = 9.8; m1 = 1; m2 = 5; x0 = 4; y0 = 10; μ0 = 0.1;
deqns = {-(m2/2) (g - y''[t]) x[t] - μ0 Sign[x'[t]] (y0 + y[t]) (m1 g + m2/2 (g - y''[t])) == m1 (y0 + y[t]) x''[t], WhenEvent[x'[t] == 0 && t > 10^-6, Sow[{t, x[t]}]]};
aeqns = {(x[t])^2 + (y0 + y[t])^2 == x0^2 + y0^2};
ics = {x[0] == x0, y[0] == 0, x'[0] == -eps, y'[0] == 0};

{sol, points} = Reap@NDSolve[{deqns, D[aeqns, {t, 2}], Last@deqns, ics}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 20}];
With[{expr = {x[t], y[t]}}, Plot[expr/.sol//Evaluate, {t, 0, 12}, AxesLabel -> {t, "x,y"}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotLegends -> Map[TraditionalForm]@expr, Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point@@points}, LabelStyle -> {12, Black}, PlotRange -> All]]
With[{expr = {x'[t], y'[t]}}, Plot[expr/.sol//Evaluate, {t, 0, 12}, AxesLabel -> {t, "x',y'"}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotLegends -> Map[TraditionalForm]@expr, Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point@@points}, LabelStyle -> {12, Black}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

End Time: `Last[points[[1]]][[1]] == 2.11774`, according with the foresight.

[image]

Thanks.

Art

Comment: Can I summarize the question as "`NDSolve` should have stopped at about `t=2.11`, but it doesn't, how to fix?"?

Comment: @xzczd, yes. I don't understand why NDSolve continues because if you decompose the problem in two separate problems and you use as initial conditions for the second one (after t=2.11) the final condition of the first one, NDSolve offers no solution, i.e., there is no change in x[t].

Comment: With respect to this and your other two questions, you should accept the answer (if any) that most effectively addresses your question. by clicking the grey checkmark.  Read the [tour] for more details.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, done!

Comment: The stopping of `NDSolve` in **Partial Solution** seems to be just a matter of precision… If you change the definition of `sol3a` to `NDSolve[Rationalize[#, 0] &@{deqns3a, D[aeqns3a, t, t], ics3a}, {x, y, T}, {t, 0, 20}, WorkingPrecision -> 16]`, then `sol3b` continues to about `t=2.07`.

Comment: So, in the original implementation you missed a state `a[t]==0`?

Comment: @xzczd I think it is not exactly I missed `a[t]==0`. My first idea was that when reaching `x'[t]==0` there would be a change in the direction of motion, hence the change in `a[t]`. In doing that, I forced that after `t==2.11` the static friction force continued to act, but now in the direction of motion. That is why an increase in `|x[t]|` was observed. Thus, movement and static friction force had the same direction. Substituing `a[t]` by the sign of `x'[t]` I think the problem of physical dynamics is better described. It is interesting to compare `a[t]` in the old solution with `Sign[x'[t]]`.