# Using NeumannValue in finite element method to replace a derivative boundary condition in NDSolve to overcome a computational overflow

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I am trying to implement and evaluate the function `GeneratePsiOfX`. The definition of `GeneratePsiOfX` is:

```
GeneratePsiOfX[psi0_?NumericQ,xmin_?NumericQ,xmax_?NumericQ,maxsteps_?NumericQ,method_]:=Module[{ode,ID,ORD,eq1,ss,as,Eqs,Soln,Soln2,tmp},
ode=2 (\[Psi]')[x]+x (\[Psi]'')[x]+3x E^\[Psi][x] Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erf[Sqrt[\[Psi][x]]]-2 Sqrt[\[Psi][x]] (3+2 \[Psi][x])x;
ID={\[Psi]0->psi0,\[Psi]p0->0};
ORD=10;
eq1=\[Psi]->Function[x,Sum[a[i]x^i,{i,0,ORD}]/.{a[0]->\[Psi]0,a[1]->\[Psi]p0}/.ID];
ss=Series[ode/.eq1,{x,0,ORD}];
(*Print[ss];*)
as=Table[a[i],{i,2,ORD}]; 
Eqs=Table[SeriesCoefficient[ss,i]==0,{i,1,ORD}];
(*Print[Eqs];*)
seriesSoln=Solve[Eqs,as]//Flatten;
Soln=\[Psi][x]/.eq1/.seriesSoln//N;
ode1=2 (\[Psi]')[x]+x (\[Psi]'')[x]+3x E^\[Psi][x] Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erf[Sqrt[\[Psi][x]]]-2 Sqrt[\[Psi][x]] (3+2 \[Psi][x])x==0;
xstart=xmin;
xstop=xmax;
Soln2=NDSolve[{ode1,\[Psi][xstart]==Soln/.x->xstart,\[Psi]'[xstart]==D[Soln,x]/.x->xstart},\[Psi][x],{x,xstart,xstop},MaxSteps->maxsteps,Method->method][[1,1,2]];
Piecewise[{{Soln,x<=xstart},{Soln2,x>xstart}}]
]
```

Upon evaluating `GeneratePsiOfX` as follows:

```
GeneratePsiOfX[15,0.001,4,10^7,{"StiffnessSwitching"}]
```

I get the following error:

```
General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation.
```

So, I decided to switch to Finite Element Method instead of Stiffness Switching as below:

```
GeneratePsiOfX[15,0.001,4,10^7,{"FiniteElement"}]
```

I now get the following error:

```
NDSolve::fembderiv: The expression (\[Psi]')[0.001]==-29568.3 given as a spatial boundary condition for the possibly automatically chosen finite element method should not have explicit derivatives of the dependent variables. NeumannValue should be used to specify spatial derivatives at the boundary.
```

I read the official documentation of `NeumannValue` but it is a little difficult to understand. I tried reading a few posts on this website as well. Here is what I think is required. I modified the `NDSolve` function within the `GeneratePsiOfX` function to include `NeumannValue` as follows:

```
Soln2 = NDSolve[{ode1, \[Psi][xstart] == Soln /. x -> xstart, NeumannValue[D[Soln,x]/.x->xstart,x==xstart]}, \[Psi][x], {x, xstart, xstop}, MaxSteps -> maxsteps, 
    Method -> method][[1, 1, 2]];
```

However, when I implement the following:

```
GeneratePsiOfX[15, 0.001, 4, 10^7, {"FiniteElement"}]
```

I get the error:

```
NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of NeumannValue[-29568.3,x==0.001] in the first argument {3 E^\[Psi][x] Sqrt[\[Pi]] x Erf[Sqrt[\[Psi][x]]]-2 x Sqrt[\[Psi][x]] (3+2 \[Psi][x])+2 (\[Psi]')[x]+x (\[Psi]'')[x]==0,\[Psi][0.001]==10.8068,NeumannValue[-29568.3,x==0.001]}.
```

So, Mathematica first tells me to use `NeumannValue` but then when I do so, it tells me that's not what it expects. I am a little confused as what to do. Also, I am using Mathematica v.13.0.1.0.

Comment: As the error message suggests, `NeumannValue` should be used as part of an equation, and not on its own as you have it.

Comment: In addition to @MarcoB's comment: 1. Most of all, I don't think `Overflow` is something can be overcomed by method changing, better to doubt-check if the equation itself is correct or not. 2. `FiniteElement` method isn't designed for IVP, if you insist on using it, check this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/172972/1871

Comment: @MarcoB Would you be able to suggest how to use `NeumannValue` as part of the ODE equation. I tried `ic2 = NeumannValue[D[Soln, x] /. x -> xstart, x == xstart];` and `ode1=2 (\[Psi]^\[Prime])[x]+x (\[Psi]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]+3x E^\[Psi][x] Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erf[Sqrt[\[Psi][x]]]-2 Sqrt[\[Psi][x]] (3+2 \[Psi][x])x == ic2;` and `Soln2 = NDSolve[{ode1,\[Psi][xstart]==Soln/.x->xstart},\[Psi][x],{x,xstart,xstop},MaxSteps->maxsteps,Method->method][[1,1,2]];`. But that didn't work.

Comment: @xzczd `Overflow` doesn't occur for values smaller than `15` for the first argument (`psi0`) of the function `GeneratePsiOfX`. So, I think that the ODE equation may be fine. Also, I can' locate it at the moment but I saw a post in this site that suggested using `FiniteElement` to overcome the `Overflow` problem.

Comment: @xzczd Here is the [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219593/overflow-with-ndsolve) where `user21` uses `FiniteElement` method. The question was regarding an `Overflow` issue. I hope I interpreted this correctly.

Comment: Sadly you don't interpret it correctly. That problem is a nonlinear boundary value problem (BVP). `Overflow` appears there because certain internal issue of `"Shooting"` method. (If I have to speculate, `Shooting` method has turned to improper initial guesses internally. ) But your problem is initial value problem (IVP), there's no initial guess here.

Comment: How does it take to reproduce the `Overflow`? I've waited for about 10 minutes, the calculation doesn't stop. Also, you haven't copied those `'` properly. I know we can press Ctrl+Shift+N to transform the code to working code, but not everybody knows. I suggest using the solution [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/231411/1871) to copy those `'` properly. Finally, if you're sure the system itself is correct, a higher `WorkingPrecision` may help. (You may also need `Rationalize[…, 0]` to avoid floating numbers. )

Comment: For me, the `Overflow` warning occurs almost instantaneously after pressing `shift + Enter`. When `Overflow` does not occur, it takes some time to do the calculation, which could be more than 10 minutes depending on the value of `psi0`. Also, I have an 8GB RAM on my computer - don't know if this makes a difference or not.

Comment: Try higher input values of `psi0` (>15) to try to reproduce the `Overflow`.

Comment: Seems to be version related. In _v13.1_ I cannot reproduce the warning, but in _v12.3.1_ I get `General::unfl` and `General::ovfl`. If I remove the `Method->StiffnessSwitching` in _v12.3.1_, the warning no longer pops up. Is `StiffnessSwitching` necessary for you?