# NDSolve doesn't evaluate unless I re-evaluate the output manually

Tags: differential-equations, front-end, notebooks

## Background

** *You can see my full program [here](https://pastebin.com/Wat3jVbE). Go ahead and plug it into your notebook. You should have everything you need there.* *Password: `OrbitCode`*

**I am working with the following NDSolve.**

```
allOrbits = NDSolve[equationsForNDSolve, allVars, {t, 0, 25 T}]
```

**Where**

**`equationsForNDSolve`** = `(x[1]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] == -((1.32629*10^20 x[1][t])/(x[1][t]^2 + y[1][t]^2)^(3/2)) - (3.30626*10^16 (-x[1][t] + x[2][t]))/((-x[1][t] + ... MANY MORE TERMS ...`

**`allVars`** = `{x[1][t], x[2][t], x[3][t], x[4][t], x[5][t], y[1][t], y[2][t],  y[3][t], y[4][t], y[5][t]}`

**`T`** = `(2 a^(3/2) (me + ms) \[Pi])/(Sqrt[G] ms^(3/2));`

*(Basically, I'm trying to solve a system of equations with **many** terms per equation. I also have initial conditions.)*

**I then feed my `allOrbits` variable into a `ParametricPlot` function**

```
ParametricPlot[drawList /. allOrbits, {t, 0, T}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, ImageSize -> Large];
```

You can see the full program [here](https://pastebin.com/Wat3jVbE). *Password: `OrbitCode`*

**The following much shorter code reproduces my results.**

`NDSolve[{(x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] == 1, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 1}]` (Thanks @xzczd!)

## Question

Now that you know what I'm doing, here's my question. I haven't run this program in 5 years. When I originally wrote this (admittedly somewhat messy) program, I was on *Mathematica* 10.3.1.0. When I came back to run it just now on 12.0, I found that a serious bug had emerged. I found that my `NDSolve` wasn't evaluating in the program. Instead, it was just returning a copy of itself.

When I originally wrote the program, the `NDSolve` would return a set of associations connecting the functions and `InterpolatingFunctions`. I need `NDSolve` to return these associations in order for my program to work properly. As you can see, I use a `/.`. My expected `InterpolatingFunctions` look something like this...

[image: Image of InterpolatingFunctions]

Now, something has gone wrong such that it just returns this... *(please ignore the pink characters in the image below—that is a quirk of the way I have formatted everything)*

[image: NDSolve returns itself]

*(+ many more terms)*

And strangely, it's only when I move my cursor to the end of this output, and hit `Shift` + `Enter` does it finally evaluate, and I get the output I've been looking for all along.

[image: The output I'm looking for]

Shouldn't it evaluate from the get-go? Looking forward to seeing any ideas you might have! Please let me know if I can make myself any more clear.

** Again, you can see the full program [here](https://pastebin.com/Wat3jVbE). *Password: `OrbitCode`* Go ahead and copy and paste it into your own notebook, and see what happens!

Comment: "Now that you know what I'm doing" No, unless you tell me: do you have a notebook created in v10.3 at hand, or you've copied the code in pastebin into a new Mathematica notebook without any further operation?

Comment: In other words, does the following sample reproduce your problem?: `NDSolve[{(x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] == 1, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 1}]`

Comment: Hey @xzczd!

Yes it that code snippet above does reproduce my problem. Thank you for your help on this. Is there a way to get it to evaluate to the association and `InterpolatingFunctions` immediately without having to re-evaluate the output separately?

PS: Not sure I understand your question about the pastebin; I tried to give you the whole notebook so you could play around with it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

Transforming your code (to be precise, `^\[Prime]\[Prime]` in your code) to the 2D `StandardForm` will fix the problem. The code can be converted to `StandardForm` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>, or select the code and right-click and select **Convert To** ⊳ **StandardForm**.

### Long Answer

The issue actually raise up frequently in this site, but this seems to be the first time it's explicitly asked as a separate question. (Usually it accompanies with other more serious problem and the answerers won't talk much about it. ) So let me elaborate a bit.

This issue will show up if:

1. You have a code sample (not necessarily a `NDSolve[…]`) involving `StandardForm` of `Derivative` whose differential order is larger than `1`.
2. You copy this code sample from a *Mathematica* notebook and paste it into *somewhere* that's not a *Mathematica* notebook. (Usually a text file, or a Q&A site like here. )
3. You copy the code sample from that *somewhere* and again paste it into a *Mathematica* notebook without any further operation.

Here's a GIF illustrating the whole process:

[image]

Why does this happen? It's because:

1. The `StandardForm` of high order `Derivative` will become the combination of `^` and `\[Prime]` when it's not pasted into a notebook.
2. 1D `…^\[Prime]` will not be parsed as a `Derivative[…][…]` by *Mathematica*.

Well, **personally** I think this is a design miss. Perhaps WRI didn't expect there would be a high demand on storing code outside of a notebook. Anyway, it's easy to fix, just convert the code to the 2D `StandardForm` when you paste it back to notebook, or convert it to 1D `InputForm` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> before copying it from a notebook.

"But converting the code will break my typesetting, I don't like it! " Then you may consider using the code [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/231436/1871). (You can save it in your `SystemOpen@"init.m"` file. )

Comment: Thank you! I ended up having to convert basically everything that this function depended on to `StandardForm`, not just the cell where `NDSolve` itself appeared. Thanks so much for your help, @xzczd!

Comment: The key point is to convert the `^\[Prime]`, so in your case you need to convert the definition of `equationsForNDSolve`. It's not a bad idea to convert everything if typesetting isn't important for you and you don't bother to spot the broken part, of course. @jack